# Why there is no twitter framework in xcode?

Tags: twitter, xcode4

I am new baby to Xcode, was trying to learn twitter integration, downloaded sample twitter source code from [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html), but when i tried to run it, it says that there is no twitter framework, and when I try to add from  'Link Binary with Libraries' there is no twitter framework!!
I am using Xcode 4.2 with ios 5.
Is it possible to manually import twitter framework into my Xcode??
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the "Twitter.framework" from now on.

Apple has switched to "Social.framework" which was delivered with OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) today.
This means "Twitter.framework" is deprecated now. It's very likely that "Twitter.framework" will be replaced by "Social.framework" in iOS 6, too.

All accounts are managed by "Accounts.framework" which is available on iOS 5 AND "Mountain Lion". If you need to implement "Twitter.framework" for iOS 5, keep this in mind to write "universal code".

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to add the Twitter framework for an iOS 5 project.  Please follow the instructions at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/how-add-twitter-framework-your-ios-project

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned there is no twitter framework in Library, and I checked in the Library folder, and also the twitter.framework does not exit....I think Twitter Framework to be in that selection be list, first the twitter framework library must be in computer and I dont have....please suggest where can I find them or how to make it appear there....thanks

Comment: That is strange.  Do you have one located at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework` ?  (If you installed Xcode in somewhere other than /Developer, the first part of the path will be different.  Also if you have 5.1 support, then it will be in iPhoneOS5.1.sdk)  If not, then I would re-install Xcode with the iOS 5 SDK from the iOS Dev Center.

Comment: ya exactly, I do not have /Twitter.framework in the respected location, and Xcode is installed in the default location..... can I copy that folder from some other computer to mine? does this work? Cause installation might not be the best option for me right now..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but it should work.  I would re-install as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

TwitterKit provides wrappers for accessing the Twitter REST API.
Get Fabric from here this will provide you wizard to add all appropriate frameworks for twitter.

https://get.fabric.io/